# Using image tag as series name in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use an image for name in Highcharts Graphs, I have tried the following approach but this doesn't to work,

```
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        name: '<img src="http://www.text100.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/icon-plug-small.png" >'
    }]
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

To add html images, you need to set `useHTML` to true option, where it's necessary (e.g. tooltip, legend): http://jsfiddle.net/a3be47f8/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true  
    },
    legend: {
        useHTML: true   
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        name: '<img style="width: 50px; height: 50px" src="http://www.text100.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/icon-plug-small.png" >'
    }]
});
```

**Note:** 
 I advice to set width/height, otherwise it may happen that tooltip/legend won't be able to reserve proper amount of space, because image won't be already loaded.